# Java - How to restrict method calling from a specific method

Tags: java, methods, restrict

I have a peculiar requirement where I need ensure that only a particular method from one class is allowed to call a public (non-static) method from a second class. Inheritance cannot be used.

One option is to use StackTrace as follows:

**ClassA.java**

```
package org.rnd.stack;


public class ClassA {
    public void methodA() throws IllegalAccessException {
        Exception fake = new Exception("FAKE-IGNORE");
        StackTraceElement[] stack = fake.getStackTrace();
        StackTraceElement st = stack[1];
        if ("org.rnd.stack.ClassB".equals(st.getClassName())
                && "methodB".equals(st.getMethodName())) {
            System.out.println("You are allowed to call");
        } else {
            throw new IllegalAccessException("You are not allowed to call");
        }
    }
}
```

**ClassB.java**

```
package org.rnd.stack;

public class ClassB {
    public void methodB() throws IllegalAccessException {
        new ClassA().methodA();
    }

    public void illegalMethod() throws IllegalAccessException {
        new ClassA().methodA();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new ClassB().methodB();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the above solution works fine, but due to quality control in code audit I need to come up with another (or rather) better solution. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: That's a very weird requirement. Why do you need it?

Comment: Precisely... normally for strange requirements like this you should think about changing your logic to avoid the situation entirely.

Comment: Changing the public method to take an object reference, and checking that object reference type using `instanceof` might be less brittle. Else write some special unit tests. But @Neilos suggestion is more sensible.

Comment: What about extending B with a new C that contains the illegal method?

Comment: Well... this is somewhat embarrassing but I am in a situation where the architect will not let me use inheritance to resolve this, forget about changing logic (that's right next to the eighth deadly sin... ). There is very little room for "changing the way something is designed"

On the other hand quality control has an automated auditor which scans the use of StackTrace, as a "Potential JVM memory leak". And believe me when I say this, the automated auditor is respected as if it were some holy deity.
And yes, the requirement is not only weird its downright unexplainable.
@Antoniossss Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to improve you method is that you don't need to create an exception to get the stacktrace, you can use the thread methods.

```
StackTraceElement[] stack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

Also maybe you want to use the class instead of handwriting the package. For example:

```
if (ClassB.class.getName().equals(st.getClassName())
                && "methodB".equals(st.getMethodName())) {
    System.out.println("You are allowed to call");
} else {
    throw new IllegalAccessException("You are not allowed to call");
}
```

Apart from that I don't know how you can do it better without changing your logic or using inheritance.

Comment: Why the downvote? How can I fix it if you don't tell me?

Answer (score 7):

The right thing to do would be to revisit your requirement.  A method that can only be called by certain other code paths is not compatible with `public`.  The general best practice is to use package-private to prevent external callers, and accept that any code in the package *could* call the method, but won't because you or your team is auditing it.

Method visibility is ultimately not a secure solution to preventing execution; someone has your .class files and the ability to execute them on a machine, they can do just about anything they want.  You shouldn't spend too much time trying to lock down method calls.  Instead, document the intent of the method clearly (e.g. "*Helper function for `methodB()`, please do not use elsewhere.*") and trust the people developing with you know what they're doing. You can even give the method a clear name, like `dangerousMethodBForInternalUseOnly()` if you really want to beat people over the head about it.

You may also be interested in [dependency-injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), which is a design pattern that uses the type system to protect (not prevent) people from executing dangerous code.  Here's a couple of talks on Guice, a popular DI framework, that goes into more detail about the concept:

- [Google I/O 2009 - Big Modular Java with Guice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBVJbzAagfs)
- [Java on Guice: Dependency Injection, the Java Way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0iSB0L9avmg)

---

All of that said, as an academic exercise here's one option for restricting method invocation to a fixed number of codepaths - rely on a shared secret.  Add an `Object secret` field to your locked-down method, and cause the method to fail if the passed `secret` does not match a hard-coded value (`private static final Object SECRET = new Object()`).  You can then use other mechanisms to share the secret only to code paths you allow (e.g. have a static initializer in your locked-down class publish it to classes you explicitly trust).

Obviously this can still be worked-around by a malicious developer, and it's pretty gross, but it would provide some sort of locking behavior assuming you can trust your locked-down class won't be changed without your knowledge.

Comment: I like the idea but is this not the same as what the JDK developers did with `sun.misc.Unsafe`. the class name is explaining it that it is unsafe and it should not be used but still a-lot developers use it. So clearly warning the developers by giving explaining class names or method names does not help. So wouldn't it be still good to check the stacktrace as a way to limit the method caller to a specific class? What are your thoughts when referring this use case withe the `sun.misc.Unsafe` class?

Comment: `Unsafe` isn't really the same sort of case, it _is_ `public` by design, and sometimes (though rarely) it is appropriate for users to call into it. When you say "still a lot of developers use it" the real question is whether they are _misusing_ it, which is harder to answer in the abstract. It's more comparable to Rust's [`unsafe` block](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html) than to a leaky abstraction in an API like OP is asking about.

Answer (score 1):

1. Pass caller as an argument and check if the caller is `instanceof` required class - multithreaded solution, cannot bypass by reflecion.
2. Get thread stack dump and check top entry - weird, heavy but possible
3. Create proxy - but that will be overheaded variation of solution 1.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to satisfy this requirement by using the class `Class` method `getEnclosingMethod()`. This is how it works ([docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnclosingMethod--)):

> If this Class object represents a local or anonymous class within a method, returns a Method object representing the immediately enclosing method of the underlying class.

1. The signature for `methodA()` should be changed to accept a `Class` object as parameter.

   ```
   public void methodA(Class c) { }
   ```
2. The legal method from `ClassB` should create an anonymous class object, and pass its class as argument to `methodA()`.

   ```
   public void methodB() throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException {
       new ClassA().methodA(new Object(){}.getClass());
   }
   ```
3. Then `methodA()` should check if the class enclosing method is indeed `methodB()` from `ClassB`.

   ```
   public void methodA(Class c) throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException {
       if (c.getEnclosingMethod().equals(ClassB.class.getMethod("methodB"))) {
           System.out.println("You are allowed to call");
       } else {
           throw new IllegalAccessException("You are not allowed to call");
       }
   }
   ```

Disadvantages:

- You must instantiate a new object every time you call `methodB()`. This may get expensive depending on how many times you do it. Instead, you could create a local class inside `methodB()` so there is **no object creation overhead**:

  ```
  public void methodB() throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException {
      class Local {};
      new ClassA().methodA(Local.class);
  }
  ```
- You need to handle `NoSuchMethodException` and change the code if `methodB()` name changes;
- Someone with access to the code could still modify `methodB()` to return the anonymous object class to another method, and use it to call `methodA()` from there. **So this is not a perfect solution**, but may be enough for your use case.